# get folder name from dynamic URL php

Tags: php, url, uri

My URL may be following,

> 1) [www.steptoinstall.com](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 2) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 3) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/index.php](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 4) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 5) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 6) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/index.php](http://www.steptoinstall.com)
>
> 7) [www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=12](http://www.steptoinstall.com)

But I want last folder name, like

1) none

2) folder1

3) folder1

4) folder2

5) folder2

6) folder2

7) folder2

I Used following, but no use.

```
<?php
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  print_r(dirname($url));
?>
```

How I can get this Output in PHP, not in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = 'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/';
$folders = explode('/', $path);
$i = 0;
foreach($folders as $folder) {
    if (strpos($folder, '.') !== FALSE || empty($folder)) {
        unset($folders[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
$what_we_need = end($folders);
echo $what_we_need;
```

Well sorry for my first answer that were waaay off, this should work proberly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work for you

```
<?php
   $urls = array(
      'http://www.steptoinstall.com',
       'http://www.steptoinstall.com/folder1',
       'http://www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=12'
   );

// The Function for your work
function getFolder($url) {
    $res = parse_url($url);
    if(!isset($res['path'])) {
        return false;
    }
    $res = explode('/',$res['path']);
    $out = false;
    foreach($res as $p) {
        if(!empty($p) && strpos($p,'.')===false) $out = $p;
    }
    return $out;
}

// Testing
foreach($urls as $url) {
   var_dump(getFolder($url));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you can use following custom function

```
function get_arg() {
   $arguments = array();
   $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if (isset($path)) {
      $arguments = explode('/', $path);
   }
   $url_len = count($arguments);
   return ($arguments[$url_len - 2]) ? $arguments[$url_len - 2] : 'none';
 }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I used regular expressions:

```
<?php
$data = array(
'www.steptoinstall.com',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/index.php',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/index.php',
'www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=12',
);

foreach($data as $url)
{
    print $url." ".get_folder($url)."\n";
}

function get_folder($url)
{
    $url = preg_replace('/(.*)\/.*\..*/', '$1', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/\/$/', '$1', $url);

    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/.*\/(.*)/', $url, $matches))
    {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return '';
}
```

Output:

```
www.steptoinstall.com 
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1 folder1
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1 folder1
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2 folder2
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2 folder2
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2 folder2
www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/folder2 folder2
```

You have a possible problem here: it's hard to distinguish between "www.steptoinstall.com/folder1" and "www.steptoinstall.com/folder1/index.php" - if there will be a SEF url without .php ending.